# Convert JavaScript XML DOM Object to Object with certain structure

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmldom

I have a large XML DOM Object which was parsed via jQuery's `$.parseXML` function, returning a JavaScript DOM Object. With this XML I want to create an normal JavaScript Object with the following structure:

```
{
    name: 'my_tree',
    children: [
        { name: 'hello' },
        { name: 'wat' },
        {
            name: 'child_folder',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'child_folder',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'hello' },
                        { name: 'wat' }
                    ]
                },
                { name: 'hello' },
                { name: 'wat' },
                {
                    name: 'child_folder',
                    children: [
                        { name: 'hello' },
                        { name: 'wat' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The original XML would look something like this:

```
<my_tree>
    <hello></hello>
    <wat></wat>
    <child_folder>
        <child_folder>
            <hello></hello>
            <wat></wat>
        </child_folder>
        <hello></hello>
        <wat></wat>
        <child_folder>
            <hello></hello>
            <wat></wat>
        </child_folder>
    </child_folder>
</my_tree>
```

I have tried something like the code below, but to no avail:

```
function xmlDomToObject(domObject) {
    var result = {children: []};
    for (var i = 0; i < domObject.length; i++) {
        if (domObject[i].nodeName == "#text") {
            continue;
        }

        result['name'] = domObject[i].nodeName;
        result['children'].push(xmlDomToObject(domObject[i].childNodes));
    }

    return result;
}

var xmlObject = xmlDomToObject(xmlDomObject.childNodes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach goes below. Using `children` (instead of `childNodes`) property allows to bypass text nodes and check Elements only:

```
function parseXml(node) {
  const el = {
    name: node.nodeName
  };

  const children = Array.prototype.map.call(node.children, parseXml);
  // ES6: const children = [...node.children].map(parseXml);
  if (children.length) {
    el.children = children;
  }

  return el;
}
```

You can use it as is, just remember to pass `documentElement` property of `$.parseXML` result - and not the result itself.

```js
const xmlStr = `<my_tree>
    <hello></hello>
    <wat></wat>
    <child_folder>
        <child_folder>
            <hello></hello>
            <wat></wat>
        </child_folder>
        <hello></hello>
        <wat></wat>
        <child_folder>
            <hello></hello>
            <wat></wat>
        </child_folder>
    </child_folder>
</my_tree>`;

const xml = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
const parsed = parseXml(xml.documentElement);

console.log(parsed);

function parseXml(node) {
  const el = {
    name: node.nodeName
  };

  // const children = [...node.children].map(parseXml);
  const children = Array.prototype.map.call(node.children, parseXml);
  if (children.length) {
    el.children = children;
  }
 
  return el;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a chance to have this written in ES5? I don't really get this new syntax and I'm currently not using ES6.